# How to apply window function on one column in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a below dataframe which captures the count of records on every pipeline run:

[image]

For the same table name, I want to overwrite the existing record and keep the latest one in that run e.g. when i ran the pipeline on 26th july, 2 new records get added def and lmn, since def already exists I want to add 666 on the def record itself, example below:

[image]

how can this be achieved? I used window function but that's not solving the problem.

```
window = Window.partitionBy("tbl_name").orderBy(F.col("updated_on").desc())
a = a.withColumn('2019_07_26', F.first('2019_07_26').over(window))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dense_rank](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank) to archieve this, see example below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.window import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F  
data = [
  ("def",None,20, datetime(2017, 3, 12, 3, 19, 58)),
  ("ab",None, 20, datetime(2017, 3, 12, 3, 21, 30)),
  ("test",20, None, datetime(2017, 3, 13, 3, 29, 40)),
  ("def",20, None, datetime(2017, 3, 13, 3, 31, 23))
]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["tbl_name","2019","2020","updated_on"])
df.show()
+--------+----+----+-------------------+
|tbl_name|2019|2020|         updated_on|
+--------+----+----+-------------------+
|     def|null|null|2017-03-12 03:19:58|
|      ab|null|  20|2017-03-12 03:21:30|
|    test|  20|null|2017-03-13 03:29:40|
|     def|  20|null|2017-03-13 03:31:23|
+--------+----+----+-------------------+
```

Then applying the dense rank:

```
wd = Window.partitionBy("tbl_name").orderBy(F.col("updated_on").asc())
wa = Window.partitionBy("tbl_name").orderBy(F.col("updated_on").desc())
df2 = df.select("tbl_name",
                F.first("2019", ignorenulls=True).over(wa).alias("2019"),
                F.first("2020", ignorenulls=True).over(wa).alias("2020"),
                "updated_on",

F.dense_rank().over(wd).alias("rank")).filter(F.col("rank")==1).drop("rank")
```

Resulting in:

```
+--------+----+----+-------------------+
|tbl_name|2019|2020|         updated_on|
+--------+----+----+-------------------+
|      ab|null|  20|2017-03-12 03:21:30|
|    test|  20|null|2017-03-13 03:29:40|
|     def|  20|  20|2017-03-12 03:19:58|
+--------+----+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, but this will impact the previous dates columns, e.g. def for 2019_07_23 will become null

Comment: @user3222101, you are correct, i've adjusted my answer which should take first not null value if exists.